# is a mini PCIe SSD worth it?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, acer-aspire

Question: Is getting a mini-PCIe worth investing in?

---

Info: I have a an Acer Aspire 1 n270. It has this mini PCIe slot that is just sitting there empty. I would like to change this, and I would like to speed up my boot time. So I've been considering getting a [mini-PCIe SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010150636+1421548207&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&Subcategory=636&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=). They are about the same price as faster same size drives of the 2.5" variation. The advantage of the mini-PCIe card is that I can have my HDD still. So I have good boot time, but still have the storage of my HDD.

What I want to know is:

1. will this allow me to spin down the HDD more often allowing me to save power?
2. Will the OS (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) see them as separate drives?
3. Is there anything that the mini-PCIe slot could be better used for?

Thanks. ~n

Comment: Warning: some mini-pci slots have room only for single-sided cards, and most ssd drives are bigger. Check if the ssd will fit before buying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the data the system needs is on the SSD, then yes, it should spin down the HDD.
2. Yes. It's making them function effectively as *one* drive that'll be your biggest issue.
3. That's a really open-ended question. There's a lot you can use them for - Recent technology is developing cool things like external graphics cards which run over express card.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of some information on these mini-PCIe graphics cards? That sounds really useful. ^_^

Comment: I misread what you typed - I thought you typed ExpressCard, not mini-PCIe. Mini PCI-e are commonly used for wireless adapters, WWAN chips, and other small but useful devices. Google really would be a better way to see the full array of options.

Comment: Yea. I've searched across Google for stuff. It seems like mostly it is wifi and some WWAN, and mostly ssd's. Though interestingly enough, you weren't wrong. Dell has already made graphics card upgrades for their laptops that run off of the mini-PCIe slot. and there is rumor about the nVidia Ion making it on to a mini-PCIe card. the concept of a graphics card in my netbook is exciting, I hope something comes of these. but for now, it seems like SSD or WWAN is all its good for. (as I already have a WNIC built in) Thanks!